# Almost-identical method with different parameters, or same method with multiple parameters for better performance?

Tags: java, performance, methods

For almost-identical methods that performs heavy computation, for better performance would be more appropriate two have two methods (almost identical except how the src Mat it's instantiated) with different parameters or same method with multiple parameters?
I am talking of course of methods in the same Class.
Examples:

```java
        public static boolean doStuff(String imageFilePath)
        {
            Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(imageFilePath);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(src,src,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR);
            Mat dst = new Mat();
            ...
        }

        public static boolean doStuff(Bitmap inputBitmap)
        {
            Mat src = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(inputBitmap, src);
            Mat dst = new Mat();
            ...
        }
```

OR

```java
     public static boolean doStuff(String imageFilePath, Bitmap inputBitmap)
        {
            if(inputBitmap==null){
                Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread(imageFilePath);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(src,src,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGR);
                Mat dst = new Mat();}
            if(imageFilePath==null){
                Mat src = new Mat();
                Utils.bitmapToMat(inputBitmap, src);
                Mat dst = new Mat();
            }
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Looking at these two implementations only, I can say that the first approach is better since it does not contain a null check. However, this totally depends on how you decide on which method to use in the first approach. Would be nice if there were more info on that too. Anyway, hope this helped.